# How do I generate several lists using a for loop?

Tags: c#

I want to generate several lists using some kind of loop
This is what I came up with so far, but it doesn't work

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //board
        int boardwith = 2;
        int boardheight = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < boardheight; i++)
        {
            List<int> i = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

I will use the lists to represent a board in Game o Life. Is there a betterway to represent a board?

Comment: Can you be bit clearer about 'several lists'?

Comment: what doesnt work? is your width and height going to be same always? for a board i would expect you need a two D stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work exactly?  You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: List<int> i = new List<int>(); line itself is wrong. You are modifyng your loop variable to be a list inside the loop

Comment: I can't use i to name the lists since i is used in the loop. The height and with of the board will vary depending on user input.

Comment: But you have used i in your code

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson You need two dimensional arrays or lists.

Comment: Yes because I don't know how to do it correctly. I thought i would work :)

Comment: you need two loops if your width and height will vary...one runs across the width and the other across height and than you use both the index to create a 2d value...just google how to create a 2D array in C# and thats what u need to do

Comment: My idea was to generate a couple of lists depending on the height. And depending on the with I would add elements to the lists. But I don't know how to generate several lists, when the number of lists depends on user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array of arrays to represent a board as it will throw `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions when trying to access indices higher than the bounds:

```
int boardHeight = 8;
int boardWidth = 8;

int[][] board = Enumerable.Range(0, boardHeight).Select(n => new int[boardWidth]).ToArray();
```

To get the value for a field use indexing, like `int value = board[2][2];`

As the other answer stated probably even better option would be to use a multidimensional array:

```
int[,] board = new int[boardWidth, boardHeight];
```

Check the articles on [jagged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and [multidimensional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) arrays on msdn.

Comment: Looks promising. what would the name for the created lists be?

Comment: If I want to access one of the created lists?

Comment: Say that I wanted to fill the top row with zeros, how would I do that?

Comment: They will be filled with 0s  when you create them - 0 is the default value for `int`

Answer (score 2):

I think arrays are better suited for your problem because arrays have, like your board, a fixed length. Lists are ment for dynamically sized collections.

You could use a two dimensional array like this

```
int[,] board = new int[width,height];
```

Accessing a cell is quite easy then. For instance, top left will be:

```
int value = board[0,0];
```

and bottom right will be:

```
int value = board[width - 1, height - 1];
```